# What default ports are used in ROS2 DDS implementations?

Tags: ros, ros2, ardent, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its seems like the default ports for DDS communication are not specified. What deafult ports do the different DDS stacks use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295400/what-default-ports-are-used-in-ros2-dds-implementations?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-06-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-06-26**:
http://docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/pubsub.html#listening-locators

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-07-09**:
Thx. Worked just fine with these ports. If you repost I'll accept as answer.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-07-09**:
Looks like you’re links are a better answer. Maybe just repost your links as an answer and accept your own? I only noticed you linked to the same thing after sending the comment.

**Comment by [kaliatech](https://answers.ros.org/users/5440/kaliatech/) on 2019-07-18**:
I don't have enough rep here to edit yet, or I would've just edited the accepted answer. As of 2019/07/17, the links in the accepted answer for eProsima FastRTPS are invalid. Correct links:

- [eProsima FastRTPS documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/eprosima-fast-rtps/latest/eprosima-fast-rtps.pdf), p.27.
- [docs.eprosima.com - advanced - listening locators](https://fast-rtps.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/advanced.html#listening-locators)

Given that links often go stale, I think appropriate to post the relevant info here:

> By default eProsima Fast RTPS calculates the listening locators for the built-in UDPv4 network transport using well-known ports. These well-known ports are calculated using the following predefined rules...

(see page ~49, as of v1.9.0 PDF documentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- eProsima FastRTPS: [eProsima FastRTPS documentation, p.27](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/eprosima-fast-rtps/latest/eprosima-fast-rtps.pdf). Usually the ports will be as described in [docs.eprosima.com - advanced - listening locators](https://fast-rtps.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/advanced.html#listening-locators)
- RTI connext: [UDP transport the RTI Connext DDS stack 4.x "what network port numbers does rti connext use"](https://community.rti.com/kb/what-network-port-numbers-does-rti-connext-use).

---

Originally posted by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) with karma: 468 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-07-09**:
Thanks, better than my "answer" :)